# I need to access data from the content provider in cordova mobile application

Tags: cordova, contentproviderclient

I am working on mobile application which was created using cordova, here i need to query some user details from third party content provider. If any one know how to access the data from content provider using any of cordova plugins?

Currently am using https://github.com/phearme/cordova-ContentProviderPlugin and am getting

> "Unknown error".

please help

Comment: Please provide more informations, did you run the plugin correctly?

Comment: @proofzy, I have added content provider plugin using "cordova plugin add https://github.com/phearme/cordova-ContentProviderPlugin" and added permission tag in my AndroidManifest.xml whic was located on "platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml"

Comment: while clicking the button with help of onclick method am calling the content provider query exection.
<button onclick='getquery();'>Getquery</button>
function getquery(){
     window.plugins.contentproviderplugin.query({
            contentUri: "content://sms/inbox",
            projection: ["address", "date", "body"],
            selection: null,
            selectionArgs: null,
            sortOrder: "date DESC"
        }, function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }, function (err) {
            console.log("error query");
        });  
}

Comment: Now my application says "xxxx, stopped Unfortunately" and closed.

Comment: Try to update platform cordova

Comment: Am working with latest android platform only.

Comment: @Randy, were you able to solve your problem?